# Is there any tool available to identify particular text in the href element?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation, automated-tests

Lets consider below href element, here I need to identify **"cn="** text in the all the available href links.
My page has 1000 href elements, in that I need to identify the href url which has **"cn="** text.

```
href="/software-advice/article/maternity-benifits-of-office-cn=welcome-inc"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following `css selector` to identify the number of elements whose `href` value contains `cn=`

```
List<WebElement> listElement=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[href*='cn=']"));
System.out.println("Total number of elements :" + listElement.size());
```

---

Or identify the anchor tag and then get the attribute value and then check the value contains

```
List<WebElement> listelement=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("a[href]"));
        for(WebElement ele:listelement)
        {
           if(ele.getAttribute("href").contains("cn="))
           {
               System.out.println("Text found");
           }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use selenium webDriver. and the code snippet is given below

```
           //Get all the webelement starts with tagname a
           List<WebElement> urllinks = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));
          //Iterate one by one until last element present  
           for (int i = 0; i < urllinks.size(); i++) {
            WebElement urllink = urllinks.get(i);
            //Get Attribute
            String link = urllink.getAttribute("href");
            if (link.contains("cn=") {
             System.out.println("href contains cn=");
             System.out.println(link)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure go with XPath

```
//a[contains(@href,'cn=')]
```

it will identify all the **href** which has **cn=** present in it on the page.

if you are sure there is only one element then

```
WebElement desiredElement=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'cn=')]"));
```

Comment: If this solution solves your problem please upvote and mark it as answer.